# Need to randomize names in a user table

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have the following query which allows me to join two tables by row number, I'm trying to modify it so it updates the subscriber table with the random names from the random name table.

```
select fo.*, so.*
from (select *, 
              row_number() over (order by FirstName) as rn
      from randomnames
) fo
join (select *,
             row_number() over (order by ID) as rn
       from subscribers) so on fo.rn = so.rn
```

I updated it to the following to make it work

```
update subscribers set 
FirstName = fo.Firstname,
LastName = fo.LastName
from
 (select *, 
              row_number() over (order by firstname) as rn
      from _randomnames
) fo
join (select *,
             row_number() over (order by ID desc) as rn
       from subscribers) so on fo.rn = so.rn

       where so.ID = subscribers.ID
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following query:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID) AS rn
    FROM subscribers
)
UPDATE so
SET so.[Name] = fo.[Name]
FROM CTE so
INNER JOIN (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY FirstName) AS rn
            FROM randomnames) fo
ON fo.rn = so.rn
```

Comment: I ended up figuring it out, but since you answered I'll accept it.  Didn't actually try it to see if it worked though

Comment: @Jhorra - I appreciate it that you marked as accepted, but you shouldn't do it unless it actually works, so it doesn't confuse future readers

Comment: @Jhorra: If you found your own solution, you should post your solution as an answer to the question.  And possibly even accept it.